# Can't absolute center an element with 16:9 overflow using the usual tricks

Tags: html, css

A Fiddle Challenge for you!

I'm using viewport units to maintain 16:9 ratio on my canvas and filling the screen at all times - the edges are cropped as needed.  This is all working fine, but I can't seem to center the canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/calipoop/vwubocv8/

```
canvas{
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    width:177.78vh;
    height:56.25vw;
}
```

I tried my favorite method (position=absolute, top/bottom/left/right=0, margin=auto) which surprisingly centers vertically, but not horizontally.  I think it's because the canvas width is greater than 100%.  But as far as I can tell that value needs to stay in order to maintain 16:9.

I was going to try left:50% with negative margin, but the dimensions are dynamic.

Any ideas?  I know absolutely centering elements has been talked to death, but I feel maybe I have a new case?

If it can't be done without a lot of css hacks, I'll have to resort to javascript/resize event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ft4ut7ry/)**

```
canvas{
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height:100vh;
    width:177.78vh;
    height:56.25vw;
}
```

If you are trying to maintain the `16:9` ratio *and* simultaneously filling up the entire screen responsively, it is not possible logically. But if you are okay with the edges getting cropped while maintaining its `16:9` and covering the screen, this might work for you.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Lcrgak/)**

```
canvas{
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    width:177.78vh;
    height:56.25vw;

    margin-left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);

}
```

Comment: yes, cropping is the intent.  Your second answer/fiddle solves the issue - didn't think of using translate!  Great solution since translate % is the percentage of the element not the container.  Thanks a bunch.